# Gurobi doesn't stop at optimal objective value of 0

Tags: optimization, runtime, gurobi

I'm trying to solve a rather complex optimization problem with Gurobi 7.0.1. The objective function is a sum of three continuous variables, each with a lower bound of 0 (default).

The optimization with Gurobi has been running on a VM for over a week now. When looking into the log, I can see that Gurobi already found many solutions with objective 0 but still has no Gap. It seems like, Gurobi has trouble dealing with the objective value 0 and can't bound it.

On the other hand, some other runs with different parameters quickly terminated despite having an objective value of 0 (and Gap 100%).

Is it possible that Gurobi is really struggling with the objective value 0 and doesn't recognize, it's the optimal value? If so, why does it only happen sometimes and what can I do to speed things up?

Comment: If Gurobi does not print a gap, it probably has not found an integer feasible solution yet. If possible provide an initial integer solution, or if that is not possible, you could make the model more elastic (that means adding slacks with a penalty to the objective).

Comment: With an integer feasible solution, you mean a solution where all integer variables are actually assigned integers (within the specified threshold)? I can't provide an initial solution, the problem is too complex. What do you mean by "slacks with penalty"?

Comment: Yes, an `integer feasible solution` is a solution that obeys all bounds, all constraints and all integer restrictions (all up to some tolerance). A slack is an extra variable to relax a constraint. This will make it easier to find feasible solutions. To tell the solver that we want slacks to be zero for optimality, we add a penalty term to the objective.

Comment: Ok, I guess there isn't much I can do without changing the problem's formulation? If a manually stop Gurobi while it has objective 0 but no gap (`gap -`), I won't get a feasible solution?

Comment: There are also some Gurobi options one can try (e.g. related to the feasibility pump heuristic).